# Adding numerical strings

Tags: ruby, oop

This bit of code:

```
var1 = 2
var2 = '5'    
puts var1.to_s + var2
```

prints `25`. I would like to know why. We convert `2` from an integer to a string `2`, so in principle, it would be `2 + 5 = 7`. But why is the output `25` instead?

Comment: there is no casting from one type of object to another happening, Ruby is a message-passing language and as explained in the answer(s) below; you are passing the message `#+` to the object `var1.to_s` which is of the class String. When you pass a message, any methods defined in the instance (or class) will be invoked: http://rubylearning.com/blog/2010/11/03/do-you-understand-rubys-objects-messages-and-blocks/

Comment: `puts var1 + var2.to_i` on the other hand...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'2' + '5'` is `'25'` because `String#+` concatenates two strings.

If you want to perform arithmetic, both operands need to be numbers, not strings.

Comment: you can check the class/type of the objects by doing `var1.to_s.class` and `2.class`

Comment: Now I get it, feel like a massive dummy. Thanks @sepp2k!

Answer (score 0):

In ruby, the code

```
x = '2' + '5'
```

is equivalent to:

```
x = '2'.+('5')
```

Try it--you can actually write that in your program.  That second syntax may look really strange, but it fits the format:

```
x = someObject.someMethodName(someArgument)
```

where:

```
someObject     => '2'  (a String)
someMethodName => +
someArgument   => '5' (a String)
```

Yep, `+` is actually the name of a method in the [String class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html).  So, you can check the String class for how the method named `+` works.

The syntax:

```
x = '2' + '5'
```

is known as *syntactic sugar* for the normal method syntax:

```
x = '2'.+('5')
```

And, because you cam omit the parentheses you could also write:

```
x = '2'.+ '5'
```

And if you don't like the result that the method named `+` in the String class produces, you can change it:

```
class String
  def +(other)
    return self.to_i + other.to_i
  end
end

puts '2' + '5'

--output:--
7
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's have some fun

```
2 + 5 = 7 
2.class = Integer
5.class = Integer 

'2' + '5' = '25'
'2'.class = String
'5'.class = String
```

so Integer `+` is numeric plus

and String `+` is concatenate  equivalent

... but why ?

Where thing you need to understand is that Integer in Ruby is an object and String is an object too. All objects (in any OOP lang) has methods you can call on them:

```
 2.public_methods
 => [:%, :&, :*, :+, :-, :/, :<, :>, :^, :|, :~, :-@, :**, :<=>, :<<, :>>, :<=, :>=, :==, :===, :[], :inspect, :size, :succ, :to_int, :to_s, :to_i, :to_f, :next, :div, :upto,  ....and the list goes on

'2'.public_methods
 => [:include?, :%, :*, :+, :to_c, :count, :unicode_normalize, :unicode_normalize!, :unicode_normalized?, :partition, :unpack, :unpack1, :sum, :next,  ...and the list goes on
```

So in reality when you do:

```
2 + 5
'2' + '5'
```

you are actually calling a method `.+`

```
2.+(5)
'2'.+('5')
```

but in reallity calling a method in OOP languages is actually "sending" a message to an object:

```
2.send(:+, 5)
'2'.send(:+, '5')
```

Anyway,

one thing you need to realize is that if you are mixing different Objects together like:

```
'2' + 5
# => TypeError: no implicit conversion of Integer into String

2 + '5'
# => TypeError: String can't be coerced into Integer
```

Ruby will protect you by raising an error. Just in case you or your colegue are doing something stupid in your code

But nothing prevents you from transfering  one object type to another object type

```
'2'.to_i + 5 
 #=> 7

 2 + '5'.to_i
 # => 7

 '2' + 5.to_s
 # => '25'
```

Another fun part of fully OOP languages (like Ruby) is you can create your own objects with `+` method

```
class SafePlus
  def initialize(first_value)
    @first_value = first_value
  end

  def +(other_value) 
    @first_value.to_i + other_value.to_i
  end
end

SafePlus.new(2) + '5'
# => 7

SafePlus.new("5") + "107"
# => 112
```

You can also override the original implementation of String class or Integer class so all corresponding objects will behave this way:

```
module MyIntegerFix
  def +(other)
    super(other.to_i)
  end
end
Integer.prepend(MyIntegerFix)

2 + "5" 
# => 7
```

> But for love of God don't do that !

And to fully confuse you, here is a mind blowing scenario is which you can actually overide single object

```
 a = "5"
 a + "2"
 # => "52"

 def a.+(other)
   self.to_i + other.to_i
 end

 a + "2"
 # => 7

 #but 

 "5" + "2"
 # => "52"
```

so in this case we are just overiding one single object, the `a` object not entire class of String.

> you will not be able to override  Integer objects this way because they are `Singletons` ...something that cannot be overwritten on single object base